# Error when SELECT...FOR ALL ENTRIES have currency fields

Tags: abap, opensql, sap-data-dictionary

I get this error:

> In a SELECT access, the read file could not be placed in the target field provided.

when executing this line of code:

```
SELECT vbeln
       posnr
       matnr
       netpr
       netwr
       kondm
       FROM vbap INTO TABLE t_tab
       FOR ALL ENTRIES IN postab
       WHERE vbeln = postab-vbeln.
```

I try one by one, and every time I put a currency field it will trigger this dump. Anyone know the root cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is your `t_tab` declared? It seems like it is declared like a structure or, maybe, component order is wrong. Try to make declarations like this:

```
DATA: postab LIKE TABLE OF vbap,
      t_tab  LIKE TABLE OF vbap.
```

and replace INTO clause with this piece of code

```
FROM vbap INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE t_tab
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fields in the `t_tab` have other names then the fields your selecting be sure to match these with `as`:

```
SELECT vbeln AS ....
   posnr AS ....
   matnr AS ....
   netpr
   netwr
   kondm
   FROM vbap INTO TABLE t_tab
   FOR ALL ENTRIES IN postab
   WHERE vbeln = postab-vbeln.
```

If they have the same names try `INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE`.
Also be sure that the fields in the `t_tab` have the right format.